# Magento 2: How to insert a recort into the database via a controller

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to write a controller to insert data into the database using `MySQL`. What are the steps I need to follow to create it?

Comment: Start with this.
https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_mvvm_mvc/
Read the whole series

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 isn't exactly A MVC system, so you'll not use the Controller to "play" with the data. This is the role of a Block.

The Block will be called by the layout xml (which is called by the controller execute method, depending on the route name).

Then inside your block, you'll be able to interact with the model layer in order to insert data.